# Eclipse Android Graphical Layout is not giving the options on properties window

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, eclipse-adt

Eclipse Android Graphical Layout is not giving the options on properties window.

example: When i select any widget on my graphical layout editor to show the properties, when i click on "Text" property (value field) it shows the "..." button to select a string. When i click on the button, nothing happens and i have to fill it by myself. The same for other properties like Gravity (i have to fill it by myself instead of show me the options like "center", etc.

I've just updated to the last version available, anyway, this installation is very fresh (last weekend). I'm running on a ubuntu 11.04 also updated today. But this always happened to me, it never worked actually :( very frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted this to android-developers mailing list and found that there is a bug (fortunately already fixed) on ADT for linux:

```
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18348
```

the solution is:

```
Download the ADT r14 preview available here: 
http://tools.android.com/download/adt-14-preview
```

many other bugs, mainly on interface design layout issues were fixed lately (and many linux-specific bugs).

Answer (score 0):

On the Outline window, Right click on the relative layout (lets say) tree
choose "other properties" and then "All By Name". a window should pop up for you to enter the desired action.
the only thing that worked for me  in order to relate action to button in Graphic layout on eclipse
(using windows 7 X64 Build: v22.3.0- 887826)